# Compare two files and display the count of duplicates occurences of a string

Tags: bash, shell, awk, count

I have two files:

**main1.txt**

```
111
222
333
```

**infoFile.txt**

```
111
111
333
444
```

I need to compare both files and display how many times each line in file `main1.txt` is repeated in `infoFile.txt`, as an example:

```
111:  Total 2
222:  Total 0
333:  Total 1
```

I've used `grep -f main1.txt infoFile.txt | sort |uniq -c` but it removes all the strings that are not available in foFile.txt, while I need it to display the count of these as 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++; next} {print $1 ":  Total", ($1 in a)?a[$1]:0}' infoFile.txt main1.txt
111:  Total 2
222:  Total 0
333:  Total 1
```

How it works:

- `FNR==NR` - Execute this block for first file only
- `{a[$1]++; next}` - Create an associative array `a` with key as `$1` and value as and incrementing count and then skip to next record
- `{...}` - Execute this block for 2nd input file
- `for (i in a)` Iterate array `a`
- `{print $1 ":  Total", ($1 in a)?a[$1]:0}` - Print first field followed by  text `":  Total "` then print 0 if first field from 2nd file doesn't exist in array `a`. Otherwise print the count from array `a`.

Comment: can youhelp if the main file is .separated